# Can I set a link of a Page On back butten of browser or android Device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intel-xdk

I am working in a mobile application using INTEL XDK.By Default android device or browser back button take back to the previous one, instead I need to redirect it to the another page according to given url.How cane I do this using javascript or Is there any other method in INTEL XDK?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the backbutton event for that button. You can find more about that button here -> http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton